# Forceing driver updates on only dell machines

Tags: powershell, active-directory, driver, auto-update

Im trying to force weekly/monthly remote updates of dell drivers and have found that the dell command update cli application is perfect for this with the following command.

```
CD 'C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandUpdate'
.\dcu-cli.exe /applyUpdates -reboot=enable
```

My problem is that i have several different computer brands in the office and don´t want to push the command to all pc´s in AD.
Any suggestions on how to do this or even a better way?

i have found this command from which i can isolate the manufacturer but do not know how to condition it for site-wide deployment.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem
```

Comment: Can't you just define that to a variable and `$x.Manufacturer -eq "Dell Inc."` ?